# AFNetworking Unit Tests failing

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Just did pod install on AFNetworking/Tests
Installing AFNetworking (2.0.1)
Installing Expecta (0.2.3)
Installing OCMock (2.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

Tests run, but i get errors in the tests that expect the error block to be returned...

```
testThatCancellationOfRequestOperationInvokesFailureCompletionBlock
testThat500StatusCodeInvokesFailureCompletionBlockWithErrorOnFailure
testThatCancellationOfRequestOperationSetsError
```

debugging shows that the error block is nil.

The tests are correctly sending requests to https://httpbin.org/status/404 (first test) or to  http://httpbin.org/status/500  (second test).  httpbin works as expected (http resultcode is 404 for first case or 500 for the second case as expected.

While the response includes an error code (404 in one test case, 500 in the other), the AFNetworking code doesn't come back with an error object::

```
- (void)testThatOperationInvokesFailureCompletionBlockWithErrorOnFailure {
__block NSError *blockError = nil;

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/status/404" relativeToURL:self.baseURL]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

// AFHTTPOperation currently does not have a default response serializer
[operation setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:nil failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    blockError = error;
}];

[operation start];
expect([operation isFinished]).will.beTruthy();
expect(blockError).willNot.beNil();
}
```

At `expect(blockError).willNot.beNil();` blockError is nil.

The error log is:

```
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2013-10-21 18:11:28 +0000
Test Suite 'iOS Tests.xctest' started at 2013-10-21 18:11:28 +0000
Test Suite 'AFHTTPRequestOperationTests' started at 2013-10-21 18:11:28 +0000
Test Case '-[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatOperationPostsDidFinishNotificationWhenFinished]' started.
Test Case '-[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatOperationPostsDidFinishNotificationWhenFinished]' passed (0.001 seconds).
Test Case '-[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatPausedOperationCanBeResumed]' started.
Test Case '-[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatPausedOperationCanBeResumed]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatOperationInvokesFailureCompletionBlockWithErrorOnFailure]' started.
2013-10-21 14:11:28.831 xctest[4261:303]   (null)
2013-10-21 14:11:33.837 xctest[4261:303] /Users/onetokadmin/Downloads/AFNetworking-master/Tests/Tests/AFHTTPRequestOperationTests.m:69 expected: not nil/null, got: nil/null
/Users/onetokadmin/Downloads/AFNetworking-master/Tests/Tests/AFHTTPRequestOperationTests.m:69: error: -[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatOperationInvokesFailureCompletionBlockWithErrorOnFailure] : expected: not nil/null, got: nil/null
Test Case '-[AFHTTPRequestOperationTests testThatOperationInvokesFailureCompletionBlockWithErrorOnFailure]' failed (5.362 seconds).
```

Will continue working, but thought this might be oversight from new version.

Comment: I'm confused at what you are asking. the 404 page is returning 500? Please modify your question to make it clear what you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: No, the reponse code 404 is expected to produce an error and thus we should run the error block.  in the code, the blockError should be an NSError.  It is, however, nil.  This is straight from the github AFNetworking project.  I am first time trying version 2.0. Previously, errors worked for me.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to do some debugging. Add a success block with logging and in the failure, log the error.

Comment: I'm not that into Expecta and neither AFN, but basically, the condition `[operation isFinished] == YES` is not *sufficient* to guarantee that the block has been run and _blockError_ will be set. This basically just guarantees that the operation has been finished. The completion block *might* run (a tiny bit) later.

Comment: @bot, I've added the logging.  Are you with gowalla? It's an extremely popular iOS library that includes these unit tests.  If they don't care that they fail, i will debug. If they can say they pass for others, great...I'll figure out where I'm going wrong. But if they updated and forgot to update a few unit tests, everyone will be happier if they fix it.  This is where they request questions be posted.

Comment: @user2887965 no i am not. But please add `NSLog` like mentioned above and see if `error` is even set inside the block. Also add it to completion to see if for some reason it is processing the completion instead of the failure.

Comment: @user2887965 You might report a bug in AFN: firstly, the implementation of property `isFinished` is not thread safe (well, the write-access is protected by a Lock, but the read-access does not use this Lock). The test method itself, isn't correctly implemented, too. (as mentioned in my first comment).